# SSRS Multi-Value Blank

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS report with a few dropdowns that are chained together. Basically a item is selected from dropdown 1 which then populates dropdown 2 and so on. The issue I am having is that in dropdown 3, which is a multi-value populated from a query I want to allow no selection.

**Problem #1**
Although that report parameter is set to allow blanks, it will not let me deselect all values. I get a required error.

**Problem #2**
In my stored procedure I have the parameter in question being filtered by an `IN` statement, which will not work if a blank is coming though as I want the blank to skip that filter.

**Problem #3**
The dropdown #3 may not have any values once the other 2 are selected.

I feel that I am using the multi-value incorrectly causing all 3 issues. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1**

Can you add something like this to the end of your query that populates the DropDown?

```
Union
Select Null as (value field name), 'None' as (label field name)
```

**Problem #2**

Do you have to pass in an empty value?  Can you do something like this:

```
WHERE (@Param is null OR t.id in @Param)
```

or even

```
WHERE (@Param ='' OR t.id in @Param)
```

If you want to keep it as a string?

**Problem #3**

Should be taken care of if you can do my suggestions for 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of **Naz at ANSA** on the Microsoft Forums...

> I have managed to create a much
>   simpler solution, after many attempts.
>   @Action parameter dataset is now:
>
> SELECT   ACTIONID, ACTIONDESCRIPTION,
>   DATAAREAID FROM     MXMSERVACTION
>   WHERE   (DATAAREAID IN (@CompanyID))
>   UNION SELECT   '' AS ACTIONID,
>   '(Blank)' AS ACTIONDESCRIPTION,
>   @CompanyID AS DATAAREAID ORDER BY
>   ACTIONID
>
> This returned a ‘Blank’ value as well
>   as all available action codes, in the
>   parameter dropdown when running the
>   report. I then referenced the
>   parameter dataset in the main dataset
>   as normal:
>
> WHERE (MXMSERVCALL.ACTIONID IN
>   (@Action))
>
> Job done!

Comment: Side Note: If you want VS2005 to select the <Blank> value only as the default, you cannot use a Non-queried "Default value" and make it "<Blank>". Instead, you need to create a simple dataset containing the Text query: "select '' as Value". You then use a From query "Default value" and choose that dataset.